# When starting nacos, it reported an error that could not create the Java Virtual Machine

Tags: java, java-8, jvm, nacos

Details of the error message

```
"nacos is starting with standalone"
Unrecognized option: --spring.config.additional-location=file:E:\Project"/conf/ --logging.config=E:\Project"/conf/nacos-logback.xml
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I have set up the Java environment variables.

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_322"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-8.322.06.1 (build 1.8.0_322-b06)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-8.322.06.1 (build 25.322-b06, mixed mode)
```

Should I check the problem with nacos or check memory size and jdk?

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of the error, the & symbol appeared in the file path.

It ran successfully now.

```
"nacos is starting with standalone"

         ,--.
       ,--.'|
   ,--,:  : |                                           Nacos 2.2.1
,`--.'`|  ' :                       ,---.               Running in stand alone mode, All function modules
|   :  :  | |                      '   ,'\   .--.--.    Port: 8848
:   |   \ | :  ,--.--.     ,---.  /   /   | /  /    '   Pid: 209228
|   : '  '; | /       \   /     \.   ; ,. :|  :  /`./   Console: http://192.168.225.1:8848/nacos/index.html
'   ' ;.    ;.--.  .-. | /    / ''   | |: :|  :  ;_
|   | | \   | \__\/: . ..    ' / '   | .; : \  \    `.      https://nacos.io
'   : |  ; .' ," .--.; |'   ; :__|   :    |  `----.   \
|   | '`--'  /  /  ,.  |'   | '.'|\   \  /  /  /`--'  /
'   : |     ;  :   .'   \   :    : `----'  '--'.     /
;   |.'     |  ,     .-./\   \  /            `--'---'
'---'        `--`---'     `----'

2023-04-01 17:12:02,687 INFO Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8848 (http)

2023-04-01 17:12:02,826 INFO Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2626 ms

2023-04-01 17:12:06,220 INFO Adding welcome page: class path resource [static/index.html]
```